# SLOC Counter Script Optimization

Tags: performance, bash, sed

I'm a HPC guy so I'm all about "make it work, then make it fast." I have a little bash script which gets a Physical Source Lines Of Code (PSLOC) and Logical SLOC (currently just of Java code, but it would work for C and C++ too). It works by finding all `*.java` files in a directory and then goes through each file found and uses sed to delete stuff I don't want. It first does PSLOC by deleting all comments, whitespace, and blank lines. It then gets LSLOC by taking PSLOC and deleting all lines starting with `#` or `@`, replacing `{}()`'s with a blank space, deleting whitespace, and finally deleting blank lines. I get the line count for PSLOC and LSLOC with `wc -l`.

This works, but I'm a scripting noob and haven't done anything like this before. What I'm wondering is how can I make this script faster and easier to read/maintain:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="C:/dev/somejavafolder"
LANGUAGE="java"
find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.$LANGUAGE" > filelist
while read FILE; do

   PSLOC="$FILE.psloc"
   LSLOC="$FILE.lsloc"

   # Get PSLOC
   sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" $FILE > $PSLOC # deletes all /* to */ lines
   sed -i -e 's|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g' $PSLOC # ^
   sed -i -e '/\/\*/,/*\//d' $PSLOC # deletes all // lines
   sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' $PSLOC # deletes all whitespace
   sed -i -e '/^$/d' $PSLOC # deletes all blank lines

   wc -l $PSLOC

   # Get LSLOC
   sed -e 's/#.*//' $PSLOC > $LSLOC # deletes all # lines
   sed -i -e 's/@.*//' $LSLOC # deletes all # lines
   sed -i -e 's/{/ /g;s/}/ /g;s/)/ /g;s/(/ /g' $LSLOC # replaces {}() with spaces
   sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' $LSLOC # deletes all whitespace
   sed -i -e '/^$/d' $LSLOC # deletes all blank lines

   wc -l $LSLOC

done < filelist

find "$DIR" -name "*.*sloc" -type f -delete
```

This gets PSLOC and LSLOC counts of 531 java files (~80524 lines) in about 4 minutes.

Edit: per @choroba's suggestion, I changed the file to

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="C:/dev/somejavafolder"
LANGUAGE="java"
find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.$LANGUAGE" > filelist
while read FILE; do  

   PSLOC="$FILE.psloc"
   LSLOC="$FILE.lsloc"
   sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" -e 's|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g' -e '/\/\*/,/*\//d' -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' -e '/^$/d' $FILE > $PSLOC # deletes all /* to */ lines
   wc -l $PSLOC
   sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/@.*//' -e 's/{/ /g;s/}/ /g;s/)/ /g;s/(/ /g' -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' -e '/^$/d' $PSLOC > $LSLOC # deletes all # lines
   wc -l $LSLOC

done < filelist 

find "$DIR" -name "*.*sloc" -type f -delete
```

and the runtime went down to about 80 seconds. Awesome! Any other ideas?

Edit 2: So now it's even more succinct without writing the changes to files, just spitting out the linecount. How would I go about spitting the two numbers resulting from `sed ... | wc -l` on the same line separated by a space without doing some assignment like `a=($(sed ... | wc -l))` and using `echo`?

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="C:/dev/somejavafolder"
LANGUAGE="java"

wc -l `find $DIR -type f -name '*.java'` > OSLOC
sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" OSLOC

find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.$LANGUAGE" > filelist
while read FILE; do

   # Get PSLOC 
   sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" -e "s|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g" -e "/\/\*/,/*\//d" -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "/^$/d" $FILE | wc -l

   # Get LSLOC
   sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" -e "s|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g" -e "/\/\*/,/*\//d" -e "s/#.*//" -e "s/@.*//" -e "s/{/ /g;s/}/ /g;s/)/ /g;s/(/ /g" -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "/^$/d" $FILE | wc -l

done < filelist

find "$DIR" -name "*.*sloc" -type f -delete
```

Comment: Can't you stack all the sed expressions into several `-e`'s of one sed call?

Comment: @choroba, would it be possible to combine the `wc -l` with the single line sed calls so that it just counts what the file _would_ be without actually writing it?

Comment: Sure, instead of `> file` do `| wc -l`.

Comment: @choroba, see my second edit for another question about formatting the output

Comment: BTW Java code comments don't start with `#` or `@`.

Comment: No, but compiler directives do

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the top (of the final program in the question):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> DIR="C:/dev/somejavafolder"
> LANGUAGE="java"
> ```

It's better to use lower-case names for shell variables, to reduce the chance of accidentally colliding with environment variables (e.g. `LANG`) which change the behaviour of child processes.

> ```
> wc -l `find $DIR -type f -name '*.java'` > OSLOC
> ```

Prefer to use modern `$(…)` notation for process substitution rather than old-fashioned `` `…` ``.  It's nestable, and easier to visually pair up the delimiters.

You forgot to quote `"$DIR"` to prevent word splitting after substitution.

I'm not sure why you use `*.java` as the search pattern here, rather than `*.$LANGUAGE` as used later in the script.  I would have expected these to be consistent.

Note that we are counting the number of *lines* in the output, not the number of files.  So the output will be wrong if any of our filenames contain newline characters.  We might be better creating an array variable of all the matching filenames:

```
mapfile -d '' -t files < <(find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.$LANGUAGE")
```

Then we can count the entries simply as `${#files[@]}`.

> ```
> sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" OSLOC
> ```

Here, we open the file we just wrote to change it in-place.  It would have been more efficient to insert this `sed` command into the pipe that writes to `OSLOC` in the first place.  I.e.

```
wc -l `…` | sed … >OSLOC
```

However, this filtering shouldn't be necessary, as POSIX-conformant `wc -l` [doesn't produce leading or trailing whitespace](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html#tag_20_154_10).

> ```
> find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.$LANGUAGE" > filelist
> while read FILE; do
> ⋮
> done < filelist
> ```

Again here we're writing a file only to re-open it for reading as soon as we've finished.  This serialises the operations (the `read` loop won't start until `find` exits), increasing the latency of our script.

For this kind of input, we really should be using `read -r` so as not to interpret `\` as an escape sequence introducer.

If we have the filenames in an array variable as above, we don't need to use `find` a second time, but can simply use the array:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
⋮
done
```

> ```
>    # Get PSLOC 
>    sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" -e "s|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g" -e "/\/\*/,/*\//d" -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "/^$/d" $FILE | wc -l
>
>    # Get LSLOC
>    sed -e "s/\/\/.*$//" -e "s|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g" -e "/\/\*/,/*\//d" -e "s/#.*//" -e "s/@.*//" -e "s/{/ /g;s/}/ /g;s/)/ /g;s/(/ /g" -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "/^$/d" $FILE | wc -l
> ```

These two sed programs are probably long enough to be worth writing as scripts themselves, where we can include comments and simplify the commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed

s,//.*,,                        # remove single-line comments // …

s|/\*|\n&|g                     # remove C-style comments /* … */
s|*/|&\n|g
/\/\*/,/\*\//d

/^[ \t]*$/d                     # remove blank lines
```

```
#!/usr/bin/sed

s,//.*,,                        # remove single-line comments // …

s|/\*|\n&|g                     # remove C-style comments /* … */
s|*/|&\n|g
/\/\*/,/\*\//d

s/[@#].*//                      # remove # and @ decorations
/^[ \t{}()]*$/d                 # remove blank and bracket-only lines
```

Even if written in-line, we should consider using multiple lines for improved readability:

```
    # Get PSLOC 
    sed -e 's,//.*,,' \
        -e 's|/\*|\n&|g' \
        -e 's|*/|&\n|g' \
        -e '/\/\*/,/*\//d' \
        -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' \
        "$FILE" | wc -l

    # Get LSLOC 
    sed -e 's,//.*,,' \
        -e 's|/\*|\n&|g' \
        -e 's|*/|&\n|g' \
        -e '/\/\*/,/*\//d' \
        -e 's/[@#].*//' \
        -e '/^[ \t{}()]*$/d' \
        "$FILE" | wc -l
```

Given that the second invocation begins with the same commands as the first, we could avoid repeating them by using a tee in the pipe:

```
exec 3>&1

    # Get PSLOC 
    sed -e 's,//.*,,'                           \
        -e 's|/\*|\n&|g'                        \
        -e 's|*/|&\n|g'                         \
        -e '\!/\*!,\!\*/!d'                     \
        -e '/^[ \t]*$/d'                        \
        "$file" | tee >(wc -l >&3) | # PSLOC
    sed                                         \
        -e 's/[@#].*//'                         \
        -e '/^[ \t{}()]*$/d' | wc -l # LSLOC
```

I also made the above a bit more portable, by eliminating the GNU `;` as line separator, and I properly quoted the filename.

When we have mixed `//` and `/*` comments, I think the counting could go catastrophically wrong if we have something like

```java
/* This does integer division like Python '//' */
```

It might be better to strip out C-style comments first, then C++-style ones.  However, neither approach is totally foolproof.

> ```
> find "$DIR" -name "*.*sloc" -type f -delete
> ```

It's not clear why removing these files is a part of this script.  Really we shouldn't be writing or removing any files when counting - it should be a read-only operation.  Perhaps the intent was to delete the temporary `filelist` we created?  It's better to remove the need for temporary files (or if unavoidable, to use `mktemp`, which respect's the user's `TMPDIR` and avoids clobbering existing files).

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail

dir=C:/dev/somejavafolder
language=java

mapfile -d '' -t files < <(find "$dir" -type f -name "*.$language")

echo "${#files[@]}" >OSLOC

exec 3>&1
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    sed -e 's,//.*,,'                           \
        -e 's|/\*|\n&|g'                        \
        -e 's|*/|&\n|g'                         \
        -e '\!/\*!,\!\*/!d'                     \
        -e '/^[ \t]*$/d'                        \
        "$file" | tee >(wc -l >&3) | # PSLOC
        sed                                     \
        -e 's/[@#].*//'                         \
        -e '/^[ \t{}()]*$/d' | wc -l # LSLOC
done
```